# Is it possible to add clickable markup/image to Chart.js chart?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Is it possible to add a clickable image as seen on this picture below on a Chart.js chart ?
[image]

The image should only appear when you click on the point associated to the image.

Please help, can this be done in some way?

Edit:

```
createChart(element, chartData) {
    const ChartObj = new Chart(element, {
        type: 'line',
        data: chartData,
        options: {
            responsive: false,
            onClick: this.handleClick,
            legend: {
                display: false
            },
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    gridLines: {
                        display: false,
                    },
                    display: false
                }],
                xAxes: [{
                    gridLines: {
                        color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)',
                        zeroLineColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)', // hide the zero line by making it white
                    },
                    ticks: {
                        // Only display time line with a 5 year span
                        callback: function(dataLabel, index) {
                            return (index+1) % 5 === 0 ? dataLabel : '';
                        }
                    }
                }],
            },
            tooltips: {
                mode: 'index',
                intersect: false,
                position: 'nearest',
                callbacks: {
                    label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                        return data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label + ': ' + currencyFormatter.format(tooltipItem.yLabel, { code: 'SEK', thousand: ' ', precision: 0 });
                    },
                    title: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                        return data.labels[tooltipItem[0]['index']] + ' år';
                    }
                },
                custom: this.customTooltip
            },
            annotation: {
                annotations: [
                    {
                        type: 'line',
                        id: 'a-line-1',
                        mode: 'vertical',
                        scaleID: 'x-axis-0',
                        value: Moment().format('Y'),
                        borderColor: '#3a3a3a',
                        borderWidth: 1,
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
    });

    element.onmousemove = (e) => {
        const x = ChartObj.getElementsAtXAxis(e);
        const annotations = ChartObj.annotation.options.annotations;
        if (annotations.length) {
            for (let i = 0; i < annotations.length; i++) {
                if (annotations[i].id === 'a-line-1') {
                    ChartObj.annotation.options.annotations[i].value = chartData.labels[x[0]._index];
                }
            }
            ChartObj.update(0);
        }
    };

    return ChartObj;
}
```

I'm experimenting with the `onClick` option to the chart object.

To image should not appear on click on all other points except the point on the 20 x-axis. As seen on the image.

Comment: Yes, this can be done. I can help you if you add part of your code here.

Comment: Use the `onclick` function within the [chart configuration](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#chart-configuration-common-chart-configuration).

Comment: Added my code for the chart @DominikKrzywiecki

Comment: @Gomer I think the easiest way is firstly to init basic chart. Next find element which should be triggers of the event. Next just add event for these elements and call function to show image. You can show proper image depend on properties of triggers.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @DominikKrzywiecki I will give it a shot and I also think its the easiest way of doing it. Thanks

Comment: Are you still trying to get something working or did you figure something out?